PowerShell : performance for parsing folders with huge amount of files
I have written a script to purge older files of our archives folders that may have 10 to 150 thousands files
the context of the script,
I don't know the depht of each folder but, at the end there are formated folder named "AAAA-MM" and in each of these, a folder per day named "DD", so the solution was to concatenate the folder name to get a date.
that is ok,
But. I can see that even if the recurse is not opening "day folder", the script generate this error : PS>TerminatingError(Get-ChildItem): "Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown." when it parse folder with huge folder, even if it should not open or parse or doing anything else than getting the name of 31 folders at worst
I may have done an error in the script ?
Maybe there is a way to empty the memory each recurse ?
could you help me on this point ?
thanks.
here is my recurse code
function Recursive-FolderSearch {
    param (
        [string[]]$Paths,  
        [string]$expiredDate  
    )
    
    foreach ($Path in $Paths) {
        $now = Get-Date -format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
        Write " - $now : $Path" >> $dailyLog
        if ((Test-Path $Path -PathType Container) -and (Split-Path $Path -Leaf) -match '^\d{4}-\d{2}$') {
            
            $folderDays = Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Directory
            foreach ($folderDay in $folderDays) {
                if ($folderDay.Name -match '^\d{2}$') {# if folder respect format DD
                    # concat folder AAAA-MM and folder format DD to get complete date
                    $dateDossier = [datetime]::ParseExact("$(Split-Path $Path -Leaf)-$($folderDay.Name)", "yyyy-MM-dd", $null)
                    if ($dateDossier -lt $expiredDate) { #compare folder date with actual date 
                    # then suppress folder if older than requested
                        Remove-Item -Path $folderDay.FullName -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
                    }
                }
            }
            #Supprimer le dossier AAAA-MM s'il est vide
            if (-not (Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Force -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue  )) { #| Where-Object { $_. PSIsContainer -eq $true }
                Remove-Item -Path $Path -Force -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
            }
        
        } 
        elseif (Test-Path $Path -PathType Container) {
            $subDirs = Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Directory -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

            foreach ($subDir in $subDirs) {
                Recursive-FolderSearch -Paths $subDir.FullName $expiredDate
            }
        } 
    }
}


Why not just use -Recurse instead of trying to do the recursion logic yourself?

hello,
because, with -Recurse, even if you put -Directory, the code will parse each item, folder and files, so it will parse billion of files to know if they are folder or not.. and the process of removing item never finish in a day, that why I create my own logic, to avoid parsing each file, when what I want to delete is already grouped in a predefined folder. @SantiagoSquarzon

Just to be clear, your current code works but throws this out of mem exception due to the recursion ? So you only need help improving its performance correct ?

yes, my problem is the out of memory issue and the code seems to work accordingly to what I want. But as the more files there are in the folders, the longer it takes, and it is in these cases that there are "out of memory" issues even if there is nothing to delete. whereas from my point of view it shouldn't act differently if there are 10 files or 10 thousands, I doubt my code as I'm new to powerShell. @SantiagoSquarzon

It's unclear if you code works or not but to target the issues of OutOfMemoryException you should change to use a Stack<T> instead of function recursion (script block recursion), which is really bad in PowerShell.
Another improvement to lower memory consumption can be to use DirectoryInfo instance method for directory enumeration and deletion.
Here is how the code would look, however it's advisable to comment out those .Delete($true) lines and host output to ensure the code will be deleting the folders you except to be deleting.
function Recursive-FolderSearch {
    param (
        [string[]] $Paths,
        [string] $expiredDate
    )

    $targetDate = Get-Date $expiredDate -ErrorAction Stop
    $stack = [System.Collections.Generic.Stack[System.IO.DirectoryInfo]]::new()
    Get-Item $Paths | ForEach-Object {
        if ($_ -is [System.IO.DirectoryInfo]) {
            $stack.Push($_)
        }
    }

    while ($stack.Count) {
        $dir = $stack.Pop()
        # `$dir` is always `DirectoryInfo`
        # condition `Test-Path $Path -PathType Container` can be removed
        try {
            $children = $dir.EnumerateDirectories()
        }
        catch {
            # leave empty to ignore inaccessible or add error handling here
            continue
        }

        if ($dir.Name -match '^\d{4}-\d{2}$') {
            # we don't know yet if `$dir` has child folders, assume it doesn't
            $hasChild = $false
            foreach ($child in $children) {
                # if we enter this loop we know `$dir` has children
                $hasChild = $true
                if ($child.Name -match '^\d{2}$') {
                    $dateDossier = [datetime]::ParseExact(
                        "$($dir.Name)-$($child.Name)",
                        'yyyy-MM-dd',
                        $null)

                    if ($dateDossier -lt $targetDate) {
                        # compare folder date with actual date
                        # then suppress folder if older than requested
                        $dir.Delete($true)
                    }
                }
            }

            # Supprimer le dossier AAAA-MM s'il est vide
            if (-not $hasChild) {
                $dir.Delete($true)
            }

            continue
        }

        # here is for `$dir` didn't match pattern '^\d{4}-\d{2}$'
        foreach ($child in $children) {
            # we can push these folders
            $stack.Push($child)
        }
    }
}


Hello,
Thank you for the help, I will check on that stack class to understand your code.
and do some tests.

@jajajf sure, give it a try. Queue and Stack are types designed for efficient recursion.
